# Would this question be considered open/opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/466/internet-sources-for-not-well-known-puzzles) on the main site looking for new puzzles to solve. Now I'm wondering if its on topic. As I understand it we classify "primarily opinion-based" questions as off-topic, however I'm not sure if open and opinion based is the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/466/internet-sources-for-not-well-known-puzzles

*Interesting* is clearly opinion-based.

In addition, any question that calls for an open-ended list of items is intrinsically too broad: a good answer would have to list all the Internet sources for not-well-known puzzles. On Stack Exchange, this invariably results in people posting answers to mention one more source, with lots of duplicates, and voting on answers primarily indicate age (no, voting hardly ever ends up reflecting the quality of the item).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be opinion based.  It also is effectively asking for product recommendations which is generally off topic on most (but not all) SE sites.  The general advice given for this kind of question is to ask about how to tell if a product or service is good, or information on how to find a good one, rather than specifically asking for particular sites.

I'm not sure how beneficial the answer to that kind of question would be in this case, but it is the generally the best way to touch on this kind of subject without having a question stray too far in to opinion based, too broad or product recommendation categories.